# Custom enum in typescript generics is overcomplicated

Tags: typescript, enums, typescript-generics

if there is simpler way to write this down as this is extremely repetitive and just seems very wrong...

```
const FolderVisibility = new Enum<{
    PUBLIC: 'public',
    PRIVATE: 'private'
}>({
    PUBLIC: 'public',
    PRIVATE: 'private'
}) as Enum<{
    PUBLIC: 'public',
    PRIVATE: 'private'
}> & {
    PUBLIC: 'public',
    PRIVATE: 'private'
}
```

I want the IDE to be able to tell me that the `FolderVisibility.PUBLIC == 'public'` as the parameter is readonly anyway.

Here is `Enum` class, it has few of its own properties and one function

```
export default class Enum<T extends { [index: string]: string }> {
    private readonly map: T;
    public  readonly values: (T[keyof T])[];

    constructor(enums: T) {
        Object.defineProperty(this, 'map', { value: {} });

        for (let prop in enums) {
            if (enums.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                const value = enums[prop]
                if(typeof value != 'string'){
                    throw new EnumError(value)
                }
                this.map[prop] = value
                Object.defineProperty(this, prop, { value });
            }
        }

        Object.defineProperty(this, 'values', { value: Object.values(this.map) });
    }

    isValid(text: any) {
        if (!text) return true
        return this.values.includes(text)
    }
}
```

The point is, that if I copy the object used in constructor 4 times, it will even tell me that `FolderVisibility.values` is of type `'public' | 'private'`

PS: I have tried this, but it will give me `string` for `FolderVisibility.values`. also, it is still pretty long.
    const data = {
        PUBLIC: 'public',
        PRIVATE: 'private'
    }

```
const FolderVisibility = new Enum<typeof data>(data) as Enum<typeof data> & typeof data
```

Comment: Why can't you just use a simple typescript enum  `enum FolderVisibilityEnum {
    PUBLIC = 'public',
    PRIVATE = 'private'
}` ? You can create these methods for the enum and it would look better ..

Comment: We have multiple enums, that all share the same class, therefor it would seems appropriate to use the same function(s). Also It would be nice if adding an enum would require not much effort.

Comment: Second benefit is to learn better how to use generic types in TS. There is so many features, but it is hard to find tutorials to them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with object literals and literal types is that you can't get the compiler to infer a literal type for an object literal property. This is why specifying the generic type argument is necessary.

There is a part of your approach that can definitely be simplified, and that is the cast after the enum. Don't use a constructor, use a simple function as that has greater flexibility as to what it can return:

```
function Enum<T extends{ [P in keyof T]: string }>(enums: T) {

    let map : { [index: string]: string } = {}

    for (let prop in enums) {
        if (enums.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            const value = enums[prop]
            if(typeof value != 'string'){
                throw new EnumError(value)
            }
            map[prop] = value;
        }
    }
    let result = Object.assign({}, enums , {
        values: Object.values(map),
        isValid(text: string) {
            if (!text) return true
            return this.values.includes(text)
        }
    });
    // maybe frees the enum so no values are chanegd ?
    return Object.freeze(result);
}
const FolderVisibility = Enum<{
    PUBLIC: 'public',
    PRIVATE: 'private'
}>({
    PUBLIC: 'public',
    PRIVATE: 'private'
});
console.log(FolderVisibility.isValid("")) // Works
console.log(FolderVisibility.PRIVATE === "private" ) // And const fields of string literal type
```

We can also use the function above to augment an actual enum ,with less explicit typing needed:

```
enum FolderVisibilityProto {
    PUBLIC ='public',
    PRIVATE=  'private'
}
const FolderVisibility = Enum(FolderVisibilityProto);
```

Or we can change the `Enun` function a bit to take a callback that creates the enum internally so as not to ever have access to the non-augmented enum:

```
function Enum<T extends{ [P in keyof T]: string }>(enumsCreator: () => T) {
    let enums = enumsCreator();
    …
}

const FolderVisibility = Enum(()=> 
{
    enum FolderVisibility {
        PUBLIC ='public',
        PRIVATE=  'private'
    }
    return FolderVisibility;
});
```